# Blender indefinitely using 100% of CPU while playing a simple animation in the editor

Tags: animation, hardware

When I play a simple animation in blender, blender will start using 100% of the unused cycles on all the threads on my CPU.

The animation is not rendered either and the thread utilization won't go down for as long as the animation plays.

When I got to: 'Render > Play rendered animation (Ctrl + F11)', the animation opens in a separate window and the CPU will behave normally. Meaning that one of the threads will work a bit for less than a second to render the simple animation.

I have made animations with blender before and did not have this problem. The program does not crash and my computers works fine while this happens. But the CPU is unnecessarily working at maximum power.

Here is a screenshot of the editor while the animation is playing (while all my threads are running on 100%):

[image]

Any help is appreciated, perhaps I accidentally turned on/off a setting?

I'm using Blender version 2.73 (32 bit), on Windows 10.

Comment: We can't tell you much, if you don't even say which version of Blender on which operating system. There is quite a difference between Blender 1.6 on IRIX vs. a test build of 2.79 on Windows 10.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution :(

Comment: Have you tried using the latest release (2.78c) or the [test build of 2.79](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/)?